# Обход 2-3 дерева .2-3 дерево как структура данных для хранения множеств

Tags: c++, алгоритм, поиск, дерево, структуры-данных

Существует такая реализация 2-3 дерева :

```
class Tree {
private:
    Node * root;
    char name;
}

class Node {
    int value;
    std::vector<int> keys;
    std::vector<Node *> sons;
    Node * parent;

    Node(int val = 0) : value(val) , parent(nullptr) {}
    friend class Tree;
};
```

С указателем на родителя. Предназначена для хранения множества . Необходимо реализовать двуместные операции над множествами (объединение , пересечение , разность). Есть идея , обходить дерево (в глубину) и поочередно брать из листьев значения , находящиеся в множестве . Как только взял значение , лист удалить и добавить значение в листе в первое дерево (это для объединения , для других операций аналогично) . Только вот возниикла проблема с обходом дерева , прошу помочь описанием алгоритма .

Comment: 2-3 дерево рассматривается как set?

Comment: @hedgehogues нужно самому реализовать данную структуру данных. 2-3 дерево хранит в себе множество.

Comment: Чем Вам не нравится перебрать элементы одного дерева и извлечь соответствующие элементы из другого дерева? (для разности)

Comment: @hedgehogues Этим я и планирую заняться , но мне нужно сначала обойти дерево , а с этим у меня проблемы , поэтому я и прошу помочь

Answer (score 1):

Да, Вы правы, обход в глубину вполне себе подойдёт. В качестве примера, я напишу перебор вершин в глубину (иногда такой обход деревьев называют LR-обход, т.е. left-right-обход):

```
class Tree {
private:
    Node * root;
    char name;
}

class Node {
    int value;
    std::vector<int> keys;
    std::vector<Node *> sons;
    Node * parent;

    Node(int val = 0) : value(val) , parent(nullptr) {}
    friend class Tree;

    void DFS(Node* current);
};

void LRSearch(Node* current) {
    //do smth if leaf
    for (i = 0; i < this.sons.lenght(); ++i) { // Перебор прямых потомков
         //do smth
         LRSearch(this.sons[i]);
    }
}
```

Идея этого обхода заключается в том, что мы перебираем всех прямых потомков вершины и переходим в каждого из них. Для каждого потомка запускаем перебор всех его прямых потомков. И так далее. Если мы оказываемся в листе, то ничего не произойдёт, так как список прямых потомков пуст, а значит мы не зайдём в цикл.

В некоторых задачах для учёт посещённых вершин используется вспомогательный массив флагов. Но здесь не нужно отмечать посещённые вершины, так как это дерево и мы знаем, какие вершины мы посетили, а какие нет.

Рассмотрим граф с циклом. Тогда, переходя из вершины в вершину (изначально находимся в вершине 1), попадём во 2ю вершину, в 3ю, в 4ю. На каждом шаге (в каждой позиции будем отмечать красным кружком, что мы находимся в конкретной вершине). В 4 вершине проверим, что 1ая вершина уже посещена и туда ходить не нужно. В таком случае возвращаемся на предыдущий шаг рекурсии.

[image: Циклический граф]

Для дерева, как я говорил, ситуация меняется. Попадая в некоторую вершину, не может случиться так, что есть вершина среди последующих (если продолжать раскручивать рекурсию), в которой мы были. В таком случае, дойдя до вершины 4. Мы будем возвращаться обратно по рекурсии (шаги 4 -- 6). Дойдя до 1ой вершины, перейдём в 5ую и закончим обход.

[image: Дерево с корнем в вершине 1]

На будущее. Большую часть ответов Вы можете найти [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/), [здесь](http://algolist.manual.ru/). Прорешать задачи и сдать на проверку [тут](http://informatics.mccme.ru/) и [тут](http://codeforces.com/).

Comment: К сожалению, я давно не писал на плюсах, поэтому в синтаксисе могут быть ошибки. Приношу свои извинения. Если что-то будет не работать, вы можете написать в комментарий и я отвечу.